# Enter insert mode at beginning of last insertion

Tags: vim

I'm looking for the opposite of the gi normal mode command: I'd like to enter insert mode at the *beginning* of the last insertion instead of at the end. I'm probably missing something in the docs, but I can't even find a mark to jump to, or otherwise I would create the mapping myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in mark for what you want.

Maybe you could whip up something with `'[` and `']`.

Comment: You can use a backtick instead of an apostrophe to move to the exact character.